# SOS with App Script for Google Sheet Form

Tags: forms, logging, button, submit

I have an input form, I created in Google Sheets.

I want to do the following:

Upon pressing the "Submit" button, I want the following to occur:

1. Validate all cells that need to be filled out have a value (numerical or text string)

- If no, a prompt asks for all relevant cells to be filled out
- if yes, we move to step 2

2. Log / Copy Data in relevant cells into another sheet in specific order
   3.Timestamp entry in log sheet, after pressing submission
3. Save a Copy After pressing Submit

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ji3aQwZ9icX2gOO33AhFz0ZU40un0bGtGWDPnFuSDWg/edit?usp=sharing

I tried referring to various youtube vids and Google searches